Context cannot be cast to android.app.Activity error
I recently updated the gradle dependencies and right after that I started getting this error:

android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

The code where the error originates is the following:
val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity

I need the activity in this function shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission).
In other posts on this site I can see that it is usually the way to cast the context to an activity. What could have happened with the update of the dependency? Are there any alternative?
I tried changing the dependencies I thought could be responsible to a previous version but nothing worked

Your error message means that your LocalContext.current is returning a ContextThemeWrapper instead of Context as usual. Please provide more information, such as your Composable code for better help.

You can use recursive solution:
fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? =
    when (this) {
        is Activity -> this
        is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
        else -> null
    }

And wrap it around let before use:
val context = LocalContext.current
context.findActivity()?.let { activity ->
    // Code
}




This snippet comes from the Accompanist library which is slightly modified to return null instead of throwing an exception as in the original code:
fun Context.getActivityOrNull(): Activity? {
    var context = this
    if (context is Activity) return context
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is Activity) return context
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    
    return null
}

Which you can use to get the Activity from a composable like this:
val context = LocalContext.current
val activity = context.getActivityOrNull()


Probably registering an explicit local would be a clieaner solution if you controll all your code.
In your utils:
val LocalActivity:ProvidableCompositionLocal<AppCompatActivity> = staticCompositionLocalOf {
    throw RuntimeException("Activity is not provided")
}

In Activity:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 
    setContent {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalActivity provides this) {
          // Your screen
          Screen()
        }
    }       
}


In your screen function:
@Composable 
fun Screen() {
    val activity = LocalActivity.current
}

More info in Google Docs
